# configure selenium in ubuntu for testing php in codeception

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, user-acceptance-testing

I want to test some drag and drop scenarios in php code using codeception for that i need to configure selenium module in codeception.

I am trying to test my php code(web guy) through selenium using codeception. but i was unable to do that.

I have installed Selenium RC Server 
I am using ubuntu os even this link is http:// 127.0.0.1:4444/ opening
but I have changed `acceptance.yml`  as instructed in documentation
while is running the test i am getting the following error

> [Codeception\Exception\ModuleConfig]
>   Codeception\Util\Mink module is not configured!
>   Provided URL can't be accessed by this driver.Unable to connect !

please instruct me necessary changes to configure my selenium module.

please instruct me how to configure selenium module .my os is ubuntu

reference sites are here:
[Selenium](http://www.codeception.com/docs/modules/Selenium)

[AcceptanceTests](http://www.codeception.com/docs/04-AcceptanceTests)

Comment: Check that Selenium RC Server started properly.

Comment: yes sir rc  server is already running at port 4444 with url

http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/console?config=true&configDebug=true

here is the configuration:

Grid Hub 2.30.0

Config for the hub :
host : 127.0.0.1
port : 4444
cleanUpCycle : 5000
timeout : 300000
browserTimeout : 0
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
grid1Mapping : {}
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
prioritizer : null
servlets :

Comment: please instruct me how to configure selenium in ubuntu

Comment: Don't know. I have downloaded selenium-standolne-server, launched it. And it works.

Comment: my config is pretty-short:
` modules:
    enabled:
        - Selenium
        - WebHelper
    config:
        Selenium:
            url: 'http://'
            browser: firefox`

Comment: can you post screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be multilined. :^ )

Launching selenium.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

mkdir $DIR/../log
java -jar $DIR/selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar 1>$DIR/../log/selenium-server-standalone.log 2>&1 &
```

acceptance.suite.yml

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - Selenium
        - WebHelper
    config:
        Selenium:
            url: 'http://url.local/'
            browser: firefox
```

P.S. do not forget to generate WebGuy (`php codecept.phar build`)

Comment: sir i didnt understand

Launching selenium.

#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

mkdir $DIR/../log
java -jar $DIR/selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar 1>$DIR/../log/selenium-server-standalone.log 2>&1 &

how to do this in terminal

Comment: it's just an script... you can do it with `java -jar $DIR/selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar`

Comment: yes sir . i did it .its working thank you. but it only checks first page . not checking next pages